# Combine output of apply into an array in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following,

```
    ID   Times
    555   1
    444   4
    777   5
```

I would like to get the output of [555,444,444,444,444,777,777,777,777,777] (it get an array with the number of times in column Times of ID). I tried the following:

`apply(dat, 1, function(d) rep(d['ID'], times = d['Times']))`

But this comes out as a `list` and I can't find a way of merging that into an array. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply using `rep`:

```
with(dx,rep(ID,Times))
## 555 444 444 444 444 777 777 777 777 777
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
> unlist(mapply(rep, dat$ID, dat$Times))
[1] 555 444 444 444 444 777 777 777 777 777
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks; edited to reflect your more concise code.

Comment: I wish I could give you a check too =/